# Android Canvas two activities - content drawn on second canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I don't know how this is possible, but a canvas from Activity A is appearing on top of my canvas in activity B.  Both activities are always alive (they are in an activity group).  How is it even possible that content from a canvas on one activity could be showing on top of my other activity?

I call this when i'm done with either activity A or B, but it obviously isn't working:

```
void clearPlayerCanvas()
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run()
        {

            Canvas canvas = null;
            try
            {

                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

                if (canvas == null)
                {
                    System.out.println("Cannot lock canvas, skipping MJpeg frame");
                    return;
                }


                canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);


            } 
            finally 
            {
                if (canvas != null)
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);


            }
        }
        });
}
```

This code simply overwrites (its supposed to) the current canvas with black.  In any case, i shouldn't even be seeing this black canvas in activity b, but I am.  I am also using  SurfaceHolder.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have two Activities running at the same time (in fact, I don't think you can).

You didn't stop the thread drawing to your `SurfaceView` in `ActivityA`.  Threads continue to run even when an `Activity` pauses, so I assume that was it.

Comment: I have an ActivityGroup that creates two different activities for which views I hold the references to, then in that ActivityGroup I do this.addContentView(myView).  Therefore the activities are both running under the ActivityGroup

Comment: I am wondering what you mean "stop the thread".  SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas is supposed to manage its stuff on its own thread. SurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost() should end any threads used for the canvas.  What more should I do?

Comment: I don't use SurfaceHolders very much, but my understanding (and I could be wrong) is that lockCanvas and unlockCanvas are merely mutexes that ensure only one thread is writing to the Canvas.  If you have two threads writing to the Canvas, one will draw, then the other once the Canvas becomes unlocked.  If a Canvas is locked, then threads trying to access it are blocked until it unlocks.